# How to get a material that looks like led lamp diffuser

Tags: materials

I'm a noob in blender, but i'm trying to create a material that looks like the diffuser of a Led light

like those (white part): https://www.amazon.fr/Lightingwill-Aluminium-dextr%C3%A9mit%C3%A9-daluminium-installations/dp/B01DM7EZO4/ref=sr_1_31?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=profil%C3%A9+led&qid=1578744856&sr=8-31

Can someone could give me advices or send me the material I need. 
Don't know where to start, everything I try is not good at all

Thank you

Chris

Comment: Could you show your best experiment and point out why you are not satisfied?

Comment: You can see on this picture, that the anodized alu looks real (to me) but the diffusor does not at all.

[link](http://www.neteffect.be/clients/chris/tl0808.png)

Comment: this one is another try [link](http://www.neteffect.be/clients/chris/tl0808_2.png)

Comment: Instead of having users go through links just to understand your question, use the tools on the site to upload images directly.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png). You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page.

Answer (score -1):

Blender 2.8 has the filmic settings a standard color management. While it does add a nice feel to a scene with a lot of contrast, it does crush the whites. 
[image]

Where it says filmic switch that to standard or something else. 
If you want any glow effects, you'll have to do that in the compositor. 
Other than that, I think it looks quite good already.

Comment: Why the downvote? imo that's the only thing that's wrong with his current version